# What would you call a psychological tool that does more than diagnose?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

There are many types of electronic or automotive tools that can help diagnose a problem, such as a volt-ohmmeter or an OBD scanner. There are different tools to help fix a problem, such as a soldering iron or a torque wrench.

The field of psychology has diagnostic instruments as well, such as the Stanford-Binet Intelligence Test.

Is there a word for a psychological instrument that not only diagnoses, but can help a subject improve? I was thinking of

> a ?proscriptive instrument

(EDIT: *Proscriptive* is <strike>close</strike> wrong. A *proscriptive tool* would be a forbidden one.)

Here is an example. The [Myers-Briggs](http://humanmetrics.com/cgi-win/JTypes1.htm) personality inventory is a diagnostic test that will categorize you as, say, an Extroverted, iNtuitive, Thinking, Perceiving (ENTP) person. You may also use the results of the inventory as a **_** (fill in the blank) tool to help you understand your own strengths and weaknesses ([example](http://typelogic.com/entp.html)) and work better with others.

Comment: I don't really see how these "tools" are anything more than "diagnostic". It just so happens that with some diagnoses, it's obvious what you need to do to "fix" a problem. With others, you may need a specialist to interpret the results and either propose action, or derive a prognosis. Your final example is just a specialised case of the former, in that you *may* choose to modify your behaviour and/or thinking, even though without expert assistance doing so may not necessarily "improve" anything.

Comment: All diagnostics help a subject improve.  Just because the diagnoses are helpful toward improvement doesn't make them anything more than diagnoses.

Comment: I like your use of *prognosis*. The MBPI has a weakness as an example in that it is a test you might take on your own and apply to yourself. Their are certain medical tools that can diagnose a problem but can't fix the problem (e.g., an MRI). There are certain tools that can fix the problem but can't diagnose the problem (e.g., a scalpel). There must be better examples of psychological tools that can "fix" people. (Classical conditioning for fear aversion, perhaps?) And I think *prognostic tool* is a step in the right direction.

Comment: I propose "psychiatrist".

Comment: @drɱ65 δ , I respectfully disagree. A DSM-IV diagnosis of paranoid schizophrenia does not help the subject improve at all. It may, however, help the *psychiatrist* to prescribe a better medication.

Comment: So you're looking for a word for a diagnostic which is geared toward the subject, so it may be interpreted by the subject, and doesn't need a trained individual to mediate?

Comment: "Proscriptive" is an already existing word, and it means "prohibiting", i.e., to "proscribe" is to "forbid": http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proscription. "Prognostic" is probably the best bet, if "diagnostic" doesn't work.

Comment: I agree: [thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/prognosis) says *a* ***diagnosis*** *is the process of identifying or determining the nature of a diseased condition or the conclusion reached; a* ***prognosis***  *is a prediction of the probable course of a disease or likely outcome of a problem*  It's at least a step closer.

Comment: @drɱ65 δ very close. Yes, a diagnostic geared toward a subject. No, does not need to be interpreted by the subject. It may be required to have a trained individual to mediate. The tool would, when applied, help the subject.

Comment: @Chris B. Behrens I stand corrected. I thought there was an aspect of *proscribe* that had to do with describing actions.

Comment: I hear "prescribe" and "proscribe" used interchangeably all the time. It only makes sense...you would think that "proscribe" would mean "written for".

Comment: Etymology is more like "name written in public, to the shame of the one whose name was written." Used against criminals and people who post silly questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could recast the phrase to be something like

> This tool is useful for both diagnosing and treating.

But if you want an adjective, you could use

> This tool is both diagnostic and therapeutic.

Comment: Yes, I like the sense of *therapeutic*. A *therapeutic tool* might help the subject to get better. It has a better register than a "healing" tool.

Answer (score 2):

There is no technical word for this, as far as I can tell, but there are words that closely approach this concept.  *[Ameliorative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ameliorative)* could work; it's the adjective form of *ameliorate*:

> to make or become better, more bearable, or more satisfactory; improve

*[Resolutive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resolutive)*, for if there is a problem to remove:

> **1.** having the ability to dissolve or terminate.
>   **2.** serving to resolve or dispel.

So you could call it a *resolutive* psychological tool, or an *ameliorative* psychological tool.  Searching [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/resolve) might help, if you'd like to browse alternatives.

If you find that no single word will answer, you could consider lengthening the description of the tool in order to be more accurate:

> The Myers-Briggs personality inventory is a psychological diagnostic test which serves to suggest possible means of personal improvement in the individual undergoing the test.

Answer (score 1):

try [prescriptive](http://www.wordnik.com/words/prescriptive)

> pertaining to giving directives or rules

Comment: Yes, a *prescriptive* tool might give the diagnostician a direction and sense of the steps that must be taken.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is just fine the way it stands, actually;  no modifier is needed, "tool" is adequate, and further elaborating on it is not only unnecessary, but would likely distort the meaning.   In cases like this, simpler is almost always better.

If you're intending to use it someplace else, then perhaps you can show us a better example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

In the tradition of *audio-visual*, how about *diagnostic-prescriptive*?